# Stop jQuery step animation with inline object as target

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

Consider the following jQuery:

```
$({x: startX}).animate({x: endX}, {
    duration: 100,
    step: function(now, fx) { 
        xVar = now;
    }
});
```

Is it possible to stop this animation before calling it again?  I've tried

```
$({x: startX}).stop().animate(...)
```

but that doesn't seem right, and doesn't seem like it's working either.  Any thoughts?
Thanks!

Comment: I just confirmed for shizzle that `$({x: startX}).stop().animate(...)` does not work: http://jsfiddle.net/UZWrY/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the jQuery documentation, you can't use `.animate()` on a jQuery object that you just passed an object to.  A relevant quote from [this page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-object):

```
Working With Plain Objects

At present, the only operations supported on plain JavaScript objects wrapped
in jQuery are: .data(),.prop(),.on(), .off(), .trigger() and .triggerHandler(). 
The use of .data() (or any method requiring .data()) on a plain object will 
result in a new property on the object called jQuery{randomNumber} 
(eg. jQuery123456789).
```

So, my conclusion is that this construct isn't supported:

```
$({x: startX}).animate(...)
```

Comment: Guess I'll try using a dummy object instead.  Thx for your reply